# Save a new Excel file to a user-given path with FileDialog (msoFileDialogSaveAs)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to save `Sheet1` of `ActiveWorkbook` in a new book, the path will be given by the user and the name will be given by me, and then close the new book.

First, I create the copy of the sheet in a new book: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy` and then call `FileDialog (msoFileDialogSaveAs)`. But this saves `ActiveWorkbook` with the new name and leaves the newly created book unsaved and `Workbooks(FileName & ".xlsm").Close` gives error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Save_As()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    Dim Time As String
    Time = Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy_hhmmss")
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "_" & Time
    Dim ObFD As FileDialog
    Set ObFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    With ObFD
        .Title = "Choose a path and export this file"
        .ButtonName = "E&xport"
        ObFD.InitialFileName = "C:\" & FileName
        ObFD.FilterIndex = 2
        ObFD.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        If ObFD.Show <> 0 Then
            ObFD.Execute
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Workbooks(FileName & ".xlsm").Close
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest you use get file path dialog instead and then do you own call to `Workbook.SaveAs` method. Not good practice to have an underscore in your procedure name in this instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First retrieve the path and filename using the SelectedItems property of the FileDialog object.  Then save the workbook using the SaveAs method of the Workbook object, and then close it using the Close method of the Workbook object.

**Other Suggestions**

1) Turn ScreenUpdating off at the beginning of your macro so that everything happens in the background, and makes things more efficient.  Then turn it back on again at the end.

2) Prompt the user to select a path before creating a copy of the worksheet.  Otherwise, you'll be left with a newly created workbook if the user cancels.

3) There's no need to specify ObFD within the `With/End With` statement, since the statement already refers to ObFD.  So, for example, you should use `.InitialFileName` instead of `ObFD.InitialFilename`.

4) Avoid naming your vairable Time, since VBA has a function named Time.

Here's your macro, which has been amended accordingly...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Save_As()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim MyTime As String
    MyTime = Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy_hhmmss")

    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "_" & MyTime

    Dim ObFD As FileDialog
    Set ObFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    With ObFD
        .Title = "Choose a path and export this file"
        .ButtonName = "E&xport"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\" & FileName
        .FilterIndex = 2
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Dim PathAndFilename As String
            PathAndFilename = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=PathAndFilename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Domenic for all your suggestions!! It works very well.